# get total sum of Interactive Grid Column Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have one interactive grid and i want to sum the amount at bottom, i have created aggregate on report but the values are not changing in the interactive grid,  how to get total sum of Interactive Grid  Amount Column values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything *special*; using the **Actions** menu, go to **Data** and then **Aggregate**. Choose column you want to *sum* and - that's it:

[image]

---

Aha; as you commented, you want to **refresh** that value once you change something in the grid.

You could create a **dynamic action** on the Interactive Grid region.

- Event: Save [Interactive Grid]
- Selection Type: Region
- Region: *put region name here*, e.g. "IG emp" or whatever that region is named on your page

True action will then be:

- Action: Refresh
- Selection type: Region
- Region: as above ("IG emp")

That's it - run the page, change some value, push the "Save" button - the total value should now change.

Comment: Yes i did like this only but i change sal value in grid its not refreshing the total value

Comment: I see; I edited the answer, have a look, please.

Comment: If possible can you please check this and help me on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71044281/comapre-two-column-values-and-validate-it-to-through-error