# Compare two column values and validate it to through error

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have interactive grid with some columns and one button as Match in my page, here i want to compare two column values and through error

Ex: one column as Outstanding which have value from table another column is Match_value here user will enter the match value amount

--> When i click on match button the below example should allow to proceed further

Outstanding     Match value
1000            1000

--> When i click on match button the below example should allow to proceed further

Outstanding     Match value
1000            900

****--> When i click on match button the below example should not allow to proceed further it should through error as match_value should not greater than outstanding
Outstanding     Match value

1000            1500****

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the values and raise an exception if they don't match your criteria:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validate_match (
      p_match         IN INTEGER
    , p_outstanding   IN INTEGER)
  AS
  BEGIN
      IF p_match > p_outstanding
      THEN
          raise_application_error (
              -20001
            ,    'match value '
              || TO_CHAR (p_match, '999,999,999')
              || ' must be less than or equal to oustanding value '
              || TO_CHAR (p_outstanding, '999,999,999'));
      END IF;
  END validate_match;
```